# How to get all unique workitems of this week in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

We are using TFS 2010. 
Is there a way to find the unique work items types associated in all the check-ins for this week?

E.g. if there were 15 check-ins done this week, then some of them might have been associated to a "task" type of workitem, some to "bug" and some to "requirement". I need to get these workitem types used for check-ins.

Can i perhaps create a TFS query to get this data or by some other way?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be queried using a work item query, since the "Changeset" relation cannot be queried. It is possible to track the workitems which have changed between dates, but you cannot limit that to only triggering on added changeset relations.

You can of course query the history through the UI or the command line, but that doesn't provide you with an easily extractable list of work items.

It would be rather straightforward to use the TFS Client Object Models `VersionControlServer` class to query the history between 2 dates and then grab the list of associated work items from there. If such a solution would be something you'd consider.